# Contact angle with an inclined solid immersed in a liquid

Tags: surface-tension

Will the contact angle change if a solid (say glass slab) is immersed not vertically but at an angle with the horizontal in a liquid (say water)?

Answer (score 0):

The contact angle is a property of the surface, and the surface tension of the liquid with which it is in contact. To first order, the contact angle is independent of the orientation of the solid surface. If gravity is important on the scale of the problem, that answer is no longer completely true - but for most situations, it's "close enough".